# Live webcam broadcast - silverlight+media services, or flash?

Tags: silverlight, flash, streaming, video-streaming

i am about to design feature for web app enabling live video trainings. Requirements are pretty much this: there are some VIP members (trainers), they are able to start new lesson (with nothing else but web browser and webcam), and non-vip members can watch it online (and the session should be recorded too for later on-demand watching..). The application is ASP.NET MVC 2.

I done some quick research, and as I see it, there are 2 platforms : **adobe flash** (media server + flash player on client side), and MS (**windows media services + silverlight** on client). I would rather go for MS solution (already got licences for windows server,etc.), but I am not sure if it is even possible - I have not found any examples of somebody doing this - I mean **upstreaming video from webcam do server, encoding it with media encoder** (this part is the question) and streaming it to clients... can you give me any clues about this please? or should I go for Flash platform for this ?

Thanx a lot !

Comment: Did you ever find your solution?

Comment: nope.. client backed off from this feature at the end

Comment: I just switched the Flex and Red5, much easier to implement as SL doesn't support encoding.